# What user or group does Windows consider Sublime Text to be?

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, atlassian-sourcetree, folder-permissions

Recently discovered that Sublime Text cannot create a file in wwwroot due to folder permissions, and that it's necessary to run as administrator in order to bypass that. Also ran into a similar situation with Sourcetree; tried to clone a repo into wwwroot, and got messages saying there were insufficient permissions. As with the Sublime issue, problem solved by running as administrator.

I briefly looked at altering the folder permissions for wwwroot, so that Sublime and Sourcetree don't have to be run as admin. But that seems like a bad idea; it's just for a local development environment, but I prefer to leave those permissions as they are and mirror the folder permissions in the production environment as closely as possible. Even so, I'm curious what users/groups I'd have to add/edit permissions for in the wwwroot folder if I wanted to (for Sublime and Sourcetree, specifically). Are these apps part of IUSRS, or maybe IIS_IUSRS? Is there a guide somewhere that has this info for these and other apps?

Comment: I would imagine that windows considers any program you run as yourself to be running as you; or if you rather I don't think there's anything special about Sublime that would cause anything to treat it differently.

Comment: I don't believe that's the case - my own user account has admin privileges, and I can copy/paste files to wwwroot in Windows Explorer with no problem. But with Sublime, and Sourcetree, I have to run as administrator to be able to create/save files in wwwroot.

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/107404/221191) on the question [Why do I need to run commands as Administrator if my account is a member of the Administrator group](https://superuser.com/q/107358/221191) question indicates that regardless of your access permissions, applications you run still have semi-limited permissions unless you take special action because otherwise everything you run would have full admin privileges and thus anything you run could conceivably do something malicious without you realizing it.